# Finding Cubesat Data for remote sensing dissertation?

Tags: data, remote-sensing

Where can I find CubeSat data so that I can compare it to other satellite data for my dissertation?

Comment: What kind of data are you looking for? Orbital data? Optical imagery? Radar? What are you trying to compare it to?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CubeSats), CubeSats are small satellites used for research missions. There are over 2000 CubeSats. They collect a wide variety of data on topics from remote earth sensing to biology.

In order to obtain data from an individual CubeSat, you'll need to contact the organization responsible for it. I suggest you visit the [Nanosatellite and CubeSat Database](http://nanosats.eu/). There you can find information about existing CubeSats including:

- Satellite name
- Organization
- Mission objectives and experiment description